# Sunspot-Rails fails to reindex in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, lucene, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have the following environment:

Solr 5.3.1 
Ubuntu 15.04
Rails 4.4.2
Sunspot-rails

My solr instance is up and running and my production collection was created by running

```
/opt/solr/bin/solr create -c production
```

From my production environment I go into rake in order to reindex and run as follows: `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`. The result of which is the following http 400 error:

```
deploy@vps194508:/opt/www/app1/current/bin$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex
(in /opt/www/app1/releases/20151209181633)
Skipping progress bar: for progress reporting, add gem 'progress_bar' to your Gemfile
rake aborted!
RSolr::Error::Http: RSolr::Error::Http - 400 Bad Request
Error: {'responseHeader'=>{'status'=>400,'QTime'=>4},'error'=>{'msg'=>'undefined field type','code'=>400}}

URI: http://app1.com:8983/solr/production/update?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><delete><query>type:Event</query></delete>"

Backtrace: /opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:284:in `adapt_response'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:146:in `delete_by_query'/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:284:in `adapt_response'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
(eval):2:in `post'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:82:in `update'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rsolr-1.0.13/lib/rsolr/client.rb:146:in `delete_by_query'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:68:in `remove_all'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/session.rb:197:in `block in remove_all'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/session.rb:197:in `each'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/session.rb:197:in `remove_all'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/retry_5xx_session_proxy.rb:17:in `method_missing'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot.rb:502:in `remove_all'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:190:in `solr_remove_all_from_index'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:209:in `solr_reindex'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:60:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/class_set.rb:16:in `each'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:71:in `with_session'
/opt/www/app1/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.2/lib/sunspot/rails/tasks.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => sunspot:solr:reindex => sunspot:reindex
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Can somebody please explain why this is happening and how I can fix it. In development everything works fine. In production my production collection is empty hence trying to reindex but it fails with this bad request 400 error.

Answer (score 0):

Well I missed out an important configuration point which I do not see in the sunspot-rails documentation.

When you run the rake install command for sunspot-rails it creates a solr directory in the root of your rails project.

Within this are 2 important files:

```
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/schema.xml
solr/configsets/sunspot/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

Both of these xml files need copying to the /var/solr/data/production/conf directory - or whatever the conf directory for your collection is. When I did this, restarted solr and tried reindexing it works! Voila.

Comment: When you did the core create command to create the core named "production" you did not tell it which configset to use.  That will either use basic_configs or data_driven_schema_configs, but I'm not sure which -- it will copy the info from there to the production directory -- not the config/schema included with sunspot-rails.